# R: Use $ on all list entries at once

Tags: r

How can I apply the $-operator to all list entries at once? Equivalent to `lapply`.

Example:

```
data(data.sim.rasch)

mod1 <- TAM::tam.mml(resp=data.sim.rasch)
mod2 <- TAM::tam.mml(resp=data.sim.rasch)

models <- list(mod1, mod2)

# Option 1
models[[1]]$variance
models[[2]]$variance

# Option 2
for (i in 1:length(models)) {
 print(models[[i]]$variance)
}

# Option 3: Get variance for both list entries
models$variance # TODO
```

Comment: If it's  a list you could do `lapply(models, \`[[\`, 'variance')`

Comment: @andschar this works, thanks! Using `'[['` seems to work too

Comment: Equivalently to andschar's comment, `lapply(models, function(x) x$variance)` is a little bit more clear to read to me.